# Getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` when generating d3 chart in node using .ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

I'm dynamically passing JSON data to load the d3 bar chart in node .ejs file. When I pass JSON in `var coreData= JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>');`, I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error. My d3 chart is not loading when I make a post call. Please review my d3 code as well. I'm using bootstrap for tooltips, and CSS to define my SVG define dimensions. Also using jQuery in some parts of the code

I tried different changes in my code but was not successful.

```
var coreData = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>');
var noOfLoads = 1,
    notdecimal = d3.format('.0f');
var ActiveEmpData = coreData.filter(function (d) {
    return d['Employment Status'] == 'Active';
});
var InActiveEmpData = coreData.filter(function (d) {
    return d['Employment Status'] != 'Active';
});
var TotalWorkingEmps = ActiveEmpData.length;
var sourcesInfo = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d['Employee Source'];
    })
    .rollup(function (d) {
        return d3.format('.1f')(d.length * 100 / coreData.length);
    })
    .entries(InActiveEmpData);
var darkColors = ['#f44336', '#673ab7', '#9c27b0', '#2196f3', '#009688', '#e91e63', '#009688', '#ffeb3b', '#2962ff', '#4caf50'];
var selectedDept = 'All';

function EmployementSource() {
    sourcesInfo.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.values - a.values;
    });
    var topTenSources = sourcesInfo.slice(0, 10);
    d3.selectAll('#Employement_Source').html('');
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 40
    };
    var barcolor = '#0091ea';
    var width = parseInt($("#Employement_Source").parent().width()) - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = parseInt($("#Employement_Source").parent().height()) - margin.top - margin.bottom - parseInt($(".title").parent().height());

    var chart = d3.select("#Employement_Source")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(topTenSources.map(function (d) {
            return d.key;
        }))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(topTenSources, function (d) {
            return d.values;
        })])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d.slice(0, 5) + "...";
        });

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .ticks(5)
        .orient("left");

    var axisx = chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x1 axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    axisx.selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("dx", ".75em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(45)");
    axisx.append("text")
        .attr("x", 90)
        .attr("y", 45)
        .attr("dx", width / 4)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style('font-weight', 'bold')
        .style("fill", "#98a6ad")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .text("Employement Source");

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y1 axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", -height / 2)
        .attr("dy", "-2em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style('font-weight', 'bold')
        .style("fill", '#98a6ad')
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .text("Employement %");
    var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(topTenSources)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("data-toggle", "tooltip")
        .attr("data-html", true)
        .attr("title", function (d, i) {
            return d.key + " <br> " + d3.format('.1f')(d.values) + "%";
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.key);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            if (noOfLoads == 1) {
                return height;
            } else {
                return y(d.values);
            }
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            if (noOfLoads == 1) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return height - y(d.values);
            }
        })
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return barcolor;
        })
        .attr("id", function (d, i) {
            return i;
        })
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill", "#2962ff");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", function () {
                return barcolor;
            });
        });

    bar.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("bounce")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.values);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.values);
        });

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

}
setTimeout(function () {
    EmployementSource();
}, 500);
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: try JSON.parse(\`<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>\`);  use \` instead of single quote '

Comment: @dimitris Thanks, your response really helped me a lot.